# Using pypy with ROS for better performance?

Tags: ros, python, rospy, rospkg, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I use pypy instead of the default python interpreter for a ROS node written in python ? I tried:

```
cd /path/to/node
pypy script/pioneer.py
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 51, in run_toplevel
  File "scripts/pioneer.py", line 5, in 
    import roslib
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in 
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in 
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

Also, changing the first line of the script to `#!/usr/bin/pypy` and using `rosrun` yields the same.

EDIT: OK, I added the missing directories to sys.path (namely /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7) but now I'm getting another error:

```
ImportError: No module named _tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66065/using-pypy-with-ros-for-better-performance-?/) by [victorp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4163/victorp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2013-06-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf uses c binding for python which are going to be harder in pypy.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gre721](https://answers.ros.org/users/28418/gre721/) on 2016-12-19**:
Could you solve to use pypy with ROS?

Thank you!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-12-19**:
No; as @tfoote said this would require a significant rewrite of tf (and probably other libraries that use the cpython API).